# Transforming a partial derivative into a total derivative via integrating factor

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, partial-derivative, differential, integrating-factor

Trying to solve an ordinary differential equation of the type: $y^{\prime}+P(x) y=Q(x)$ Wikipedia states:
"To derive this, let $M_{(x)}$ be the integrating factor of a first order linear differential equation such that multiplication by $M_{(x)}$ transforms a partial derivative into a total derivative:

$M(x)(\underbrace{y^{\prime}+P(x) y}_{\text {partial derivative }}) = \underbrace{M(x) y^{\prime}+M^{\prime}(x) y}_{\text {total derivative }}$ .  "

I cannot understand in what way is $y^{\prime}+P(x) y$  a partial derivative and $M(x) y^{\prime}+M^{\prime}(x) y$ a total derivative.

Could someone try to explain this? thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The terminology is a little confusing. "Partial derivative" as used here does not mean the same thing as the much better known "partial derivative" of multivariate calculus.

Basically, $My' + M'y$ is a "total derivative" because there is a function $f(M, y)$ (i.e., one not directly dependent on $x$) such that $$\dfrac{d}{dx}f(M, y) = M\dfrac{dy}{dx} + \dfrac{dM}{dx}y$$

In this case, obviously $f(M,y) = My$. I'm not completely sure of the reason for the particular terminology. But note that if you "multiply through by $dx$" you get the differential equation
$$df = Mdy + ydM$$
which does not include $dx$ anymore. When such a function $f$ exists, the expression on the right ($Mdy + ydM$ in this case) is called an "exact differential".

On the other hand, the similar expression for the other side would be $dg = dy + Pydx$. Such a $g$ must explicitly depend on $x$, not just $y$ and $P$. This is why that side is only "partial".

The great thing here is that you can find a function $M$ that can be multiplied by the "partial" derivative to make it a "total" derivative.

Comment: Thank you! I guess calling it a "partial derivative" is just incorrect then, considering that the term is already reserved for something else which is well defined.

Comment: You have to be careful with that - I wouldn't be surprised if this were the older meaning of "partial derivative". Things go in and out of fashion over time. When I was in school, every textbook I saw had $\Bbb N$ start at one. But now, there are people who have always seen $0\in \Bbb N$ and are nonplussed by the very idea of leaving $0$ out.